# How can I reach the Announcement/RSS Page from a Steam Game Page?

Tags: steam

I created a Selenium Script that iterates though all the game URLS i have in a list (ie `https://store.steampowered.com/app/400910` or `https://store.steampowered.com/app/233450`) and looks for the link to the Announcements page (ie. `https://steamcommunity.com/games/rabi-ribi/announcements` or `https://steamcommunity.com/games/233450/announcements`) and goes to this page to get the URL behind the "Subscribe to RSS Feed" (ie. `https://steamcommunity.com/games/rabi-ribi/rss/` or `https://steamcommunity.com/games/233450/rss/`). This has come in handy for creating an import for RSSOwl to track the news for 700+ Steam games.

However it seems Steam has changed the Browser UI and I can no longer find a link to the Announcements page to then get the RSS URL.

Now I can't "guess" the URL with the ID as with the 2 games I provided as examples. *Rabi Ribi* doesn't use a Steam ID in its URL and if I try to use the ID (ie. `https://steamcommunity.com/games/400910/rss/`) it'll 404 and it'll be blind shots in the dark to try and find a variation of the game's title that'll work.

How can I reach the Announcement/RSS Page from a Steam Game Page?

Comment: The only way I could see this, is by following the game from the community hub, and then looking in my activity feed. Where it says '*<X> is now following <Y>*' the <Y> would link to either the [numerical id](https://steamcommunity.com/games/435150) or (for Rabi-Ribi) the [game name](https://steamcommunity.com/games/rabi-ribi) code. Interestingly these seem to be the '*official group*' pages, so if there's some way to find that, perhaps that might help.

Comment: Steam is probably leaning away from RSS and more towards webservices like Steam's [`GetNewsForApp`](https://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/Steam_Web_API#GetNewsForApp_.28v0002.29) service (which takes an appid).